# How to detect files with the same name but different extensions?

Tags: directory, delete, batch

I have a directory whose files have extension either .JPG or .NEF and I want to delete the files of the form X.NEF for which X.JPG does not exist in the directory. (X here can be any string.) I don't know how to do this other than by hand.

A more general situation is when you want to find all the files in a directory A which exist in directory B as well. (The first problem can be turned into the second one using `mmv`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the shell's `${var%ext}` parameter substitution features to remove the original extension on a per-file basis: to illustrate

```
touch file{1..6}.NEF file{1,2,4,6}.JPG
```

Then

```
for nef in *.NEF; do [[ -f "${nef%.NEF}.JPG" ]] || echo rm -- "$nef"; done
```

results in

```
rm -- file3.NEF
rm -- file5.NEF
```

Explanation:

The first command just creates 6 `.NEF` files numbered `file1.NEF` to `file6.NEF` and corresponding `.JPG` files for 3 of them i.e. just some empty files to test the second command on.

Comment: @terdon Ooops I just realize I "stole" your more compact version in my edit. BTW is `-e` or `-f` preferred for the test here in your opinion?

Comment: Could you explain what the first command does?

Comment: @steeldriver I think  `-f` is better since it doesn't consider directories as valid hits. I just found out it does accept symlinks (despite claiming to be about "regular" files) which was my reason for using `-e` instead. And "steal" away, it's not like it's a form you hadn't seen before :)

Comment: @Reza the first command just creates 6 `.NEF` files numbered `file1.NEF` to `file6.NEF` and corresponding `.JPG` files for 3 of them i.e. just some empty files to test the second command on

Comment: @steeldriver I moved your explanation into your answer - maybe you'd like to explain the rest of your fine commands too?

Comment: THANK YOU! Worked perfectly. for anyone trying to do other complex directory level renames, I recommend the `rename` package.